# Changing the default instructions in Alfresco 5.1 searchbox

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-module-package

I have successfully created a number of amps to customize Alfresco 5.1. The one change that aludes me, is to develop an amp to change the default text in the searchbox. The text currently is "Search files, people, sites" and I want it to say "Search Reports". I can force the change by modifiying the line in the Aikau jar which contains the "search.instructions=Search files, people, sites" but this will not hold if we upgrade to the newer version of Alfresco.instruction which is different than the search placeholder text. Let me know what version of Aikua you are using.

Comment: Thank you, Sanjay.  This does not work for me.  What am I missing?  It was suggested that I upgrade Aikau but I am already running the latest one.  Any other suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

You can user module deployment approach for this.

```
Create .xml file within web-extension/site-data/extensions/share-module.xml

<extension>
  <modules>
    <module>
      <id>AAAAA</id>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <auto-deploy>true</auto-deploy>  
      <customizations>
        <customization>
          <targetPackageRoot>org.alfresco.share.header</targetPackageRoot>
          <sourcePackageRoot>com.menu</sourcePackageRoot>
        </customization>
      </customizations>
    </module>
  </modules>
</extension>



Create .js file within web-extension/site-webscripts/com/menu/share-header.get.js

var searchBox = widgetUtils.findObject(model.jsonModel.widgets, "id", "HEADER_SEARCH");
searchBox.config.placeholder= "search-custom.label";
```